# Printing an integer with a float conversion code (%f)?

Tags: c

So I've been looking into c programming and bought a book. There's a problem at the end of a chapter that reads:

write a program that defines five integer variables and initializes them to 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000. It then prints them on a single line separated by space characters using the decimal conversion code (%d), and on the nest line with the float conversion code (%f). Note the differences between the results. How do you explain to them?

Now, my question is how do you use the float conversion code for a number that is defined as an int?

This is what I have written so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int one = 1; 
    int ten = 10;
    int hundred = 100; 
    int thousand = 1000;
    int tenThous = 100000;

    printf("%d %d %d %d %d \n", one, ten, hundred, thousand, tenThous);
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f \n", one, ten, hundred, thousand, tenThous);

    return 0; 
}
```

In the way they describe the problem, I think I have to use the int variables that I had defined. It would be easy to make a new set of numbers and declare them as floats, but I don't think this is exactly what they're asking.

The error message that I get when compiling is:

```
numPrint.c:12:33: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has
      type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%f %f %f %f %f \n", one, ten, hundred, thousand, tenThous);
            ~~                  ^~~
            %d
```

and it goes through all the int variables, saying that the format specifies for a 'double' and the variable used is 'int'

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How about `printf("%f %f %f %f %f \n", (float)one, (float)ten, (float)hundred, (float)thousand, (float)tenThous);`?

Comment: That works!! wow, we haven't learned about casting yet in the book so I think it's weird that it would as a question like this. Thank you! :)

Comment: @AwaisChishti You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @lucas: the warning is what they want you to learn about. And what happens if you ignore the warning -- a warning is not an error, so you can ignore. (Not a good idea, but possible.) I think you did not try running the bad code. Try it. Then read up on Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: @NikosC. Sure thing

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to do this?

You *have* done it.  The messages are warnings; they will not have aborted compilation.

Or maybe you're asking whether you can do it without eliciting warnings?  Sure you can.  The message tells you what warning flag that particular diagnostic is associated with: `-Wformat`.  You can disable those warnings by passing `-Wno-format` as a command-line option.

But you shouldn't.

The warnings are telling you about a *bona fide* problem in your code.  Just as it explains, the `%f` descriptor expects the corresponding argument to have type `double`. Alternatively, `float` will work, too, since it is automatically converted to `double` in this particular context, but if the argument has a different type then the behavior is undefined.  You could cast the arguments to type `double`, but that's not what I interpret the text to be asking you to do.

What should you do instead?  Burn the book and get a better one.  Really.  There is no justification for a textbook on C to suggest doing what yours seems to have suggested.  Even if it's just poorly worded, you have to wonder what other stinkers are waiting for you there.  Burning the book instead of returning it or giving it away constitutes a community service.

Comment: Reference - [C11 Standard - 7.21.6.1 The fprintf function(p9)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9) *...If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.*

Comment: I don't say that necessarily is a sign of a bad book, if chapter 2 is "undefined behavior"

Comment: It's kind of like a driver's training book advising you to drive through a red light and see what happens, or crash into a brick wall and see what happens.  And it's true, in either case you *might* learn a valuable lesson.  (But in the first case you might not learn the lesson, if nothing bad happens, and in the second case you might end up dead.)

Answer (score 1):

You can cast the `printf()` arguments to floats like this:

```
printf("%f %f %f %f %f \n", (float)one, (float)ten, (float)hundred, (float)thousand, (float)tenThous);
```

Comment: Although this will certainly work around the warnings, (1) it would be better to cast straight to `double`, since that's the wanted type, and (2) this does not seem at all to be the textbook's intent.